# How do you use etc. with or?

Tags: lists

I have a sentence where I want to say that X is one of several things in a category, i.e.

"...where X is an A, B, C, or D, etc."  The elements A, B, C, or D are not exhaustive, so I want to include etc. to indicate that, but I don't know where to place etc.

Comment: "...where X is an A or B or C or ..."

Comment: So if that's the end of the sentence, I just use four periods?  That always seemed a bit awkward to me.

Comment: You do not use four periods. In fact, where are you seeing four periods? I am quite confused. Did you mean to comment on a different question?

Comment: Well, when I searched online, sources seemed to recommend using four periods for ellipsis at the end of a sentence.  With three periods, wouldn't it look strange?  E.g. "You should use an X, where X is an A or  or C or ...  Furthermore, this is a different sentence."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's awkward is because *etc.* means “and other things”: *et cetera*. For your use, you need “or other things”, for which there is no Latin phrase in English (it would use *vel,* the Latin for *or*) and consequently no abbreviation.

This is a pity, because we are reduced to spelling out the alternatives. There's no handy three-letter doobry to use.

> ...where X is an A, B, C, D or some such.

You could use *inter alia,* “among others”, to indicate that other choices are available. You might get away with *inter al.* or even *int. al.,* but it’s normally spelled in full.

> ...where X is an A, B, C or D, *inter alia*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you simply need to omit the "or" from your list:
"...where X is an A, B, C, D, etc." Et cetera becomes part of your list, meaning "and others", or "and so on".

Comment: And the full stop after etc is dual-purpose if you prefer using 'etc.' or single-purpose if you have simplified to 'etc', 'ie', 'eg' etc. (I _have_ found an 'authority' licensing the dropping of full stops from Latin-sourced abbreviations.) (I suppose I ought also to mention another 'authority' I found recommending the dropping of Latin-sourced abbreviations.)